# Generate multiple tables with multiple links in each table (webpage)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a webpage which needs to show multiple tables in the same format, but with different numbers inside + **generate appropriate links inside many of the table cells.**

*Design*: The webpage will show 1 table for each School subject, and then the cells inside will show how different homeroom classes have been doing under their teachers guidance, using SAT scores, final exams, and attendance rates. The teacher's names and the subject names must link to another page which displays more info about that specific teacher/subject.

I used to use php to generate tables, but seeing as there needs to be links as well inside these table, and very "customized" ones at that, I'm not sure where to start. Each link is totally **unique**, no complete duplicates. And with say 6 subjects, and 5 teachers, there will be 36 unique links which must be generated.

Currently I have an sql table with: subject, homeroom_teacher, subject_SAT_rslt_change, sat_retake_count, Final_vs_mid, improved_students_count, attendance_rate, missing_student_count

Below, I have put an html example of the type of table I want to generate for a given subject.

```
<!--subjects: math, science, literature, art, history, physical education-->
    <table>
  <tr>
<th colspan="7"<a href="allsubjects.php?subject=math" style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">Math</b></th>  </tr>
  <tr id="tr01">
  <td><b>  Homeroom Teacher </b> </td>
    <td><b>  Subject SAT result change </b> </td>
    <td><b>  Retake count</b>  </td>
    <td><b>  Finals vs midterm difference  </b></td>
    <td><b>  Improved students count  </b></td>
    <td><b>  Attendance rates  </b></td>
    <td><b>  Students missing class  </b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><a href="xyz.php?subject=math">Mrs. Xyz </td>
    <td>-1% </td>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td>+22% </td>
    <td>2 </td>
    <td>-2% </td>
    <td>5 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><a href="abc.php?subject=math">Mr. Abc </td>
    <td>-22% </td>
    <td>2 </td>
    <td>+1% </td>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td>-6% </td>
    <td>1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="msa.php?subject=math">Ms. A </td>
    <td>-2% </td>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>+10% </td>
    <td>32 </td>
    <td>-2% </td>
    <td>0 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

php

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");
  if($mysqli->connect_errno)
    die("Connection failed".$mysqli->connect_error);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `table1` where subject='math';";
$query .=  "SELECT * FROM `table1` where subject='literature';";
  $query .=  "SELECT * FROM `table1` where subject='science';";

  if($mysqli->multi_query($query))
  {
    $i=0;
    do{
      $result = $mysqli->store_result();
    
      
      $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
      $title = '';

      $table = '';
      $i=0;
      foreach($finfo as $f)
      {
        if($i!=0)
          $table = $table. "<th>".$f->name."</th>";
        $i++;
      }
      $table = $table. "</tr>";
      
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        $table = $table. "<tr>";
        $j=0;
        foreach($row as $v)
        {
          if($j==0) {
            $title=$v;
          
          } else {
          $table = $table. "<td>".$v."</td>";
          }
          $j++;
        }
        $table = $table. "</tr>";
      }

      echo "<table>";
      echo "<tr><th><b>".$title."</b></th></tr>";
      echo $table;
      echo "</table>";
    }while($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
  }
  
?>
```

SQL:

```
insert into table1('math','mrs.xyz','-1%',3,'+22%',2,'-2%',5);
```

I have tagged javascript and php as I need to use them, but if you know of solutions in other languages you are also welcome to post them.

Comment: Look up "PHP alternative syntax" and just output the database values into your HTML.

Comment: If you can use PHP to generate tables, I don't see why you can't use it to generate links. Specifically what are you struggling with?

Comment: @GregSchmidt because usually it would be something like echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Link</a>"; but here, there are a lot of tables and table cells which each need their own link (ie. abc.php?subject=math. xyz.php?subject=math, etc). So its confusing where to start or how to do that when normally I would use a loop to to generate multiple tables that just show data from the database only(but with no links).

Comment: How are these links determined? Is it not from data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

use " double quote and single quote properly that's all,

```
$finfo = $result->fetch_fields(); *///example variable*

echo "<a hrea='".$finfo.".php'>Link text </a> ";

another way :
<a href = "<?PHP echo $finfo;?>">Link text </a>
```